# Show that $\det(P(t))=\det(P_0) e^{\int_0^t \operatorname{Tr} A(s)\, ds}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, systems-of-equations, initial-value-problems

Let $A(t)$ be a continuous family of $n \times n$ matrices and let $P(t)$ be the matrix solution to the initial value problem $P'(t)=A(t)P$, where $P(0)=P_0$. Show that $$\det(P(t))=\det(P_0) e^{\int_0^t \operatorname{Tr} A(s)\, ds}.$$

If we consider $A(t)=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    a & b  \\
    c & d  \\   
    \end{pmatrix}$, $P(t)=
    \begin{pmatrix}
    x_1 & y_1  \\
    x_2 & y_2  \\   
    \end{pmatrix}$, and $W(t)=\det (P(t))$ then $W'=\operatorname {Tr}(A) W$.

My question is how do I solve the last system?

And I just consider  $2\times 2$ matrix, but the result follows easily for an $n\times n$ matrix; am I right?

Comment: well I have a result in my notes that says $P(t)=e^{At}P_0$, for A a matrix, $P_0\in \mathbb R^n.$

Comment: @user486983 $ W'=\text{Tr}(A)W $ can be solved just by integration, because $\text{Tr}(A(t))$ will be just a real valued function of $t$.

Comment: @user486983 Also $\text{det}(P(t))$ is a real valued function of $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given $P'(t)=A(t)P, ~ P(0)=P_{0}$. Let $W(t)=\text{det}(P(t))$ and suppose that $p_{1}(t),...,p_{n}(t)$ be column vectors of $P(t)$. Since determinant is multilinear function, derivative can be determined as $$ W'(t)=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \text{det}(p_{1}(t),...,p'_{k}(t),...,p_{n}(t)) $$
$$ =\sum_{k=1}^{n} \text{det}(p_{1}(t),...,A(t)p_{k}(t),...,p_{n}(t)) $$
$$ = \text{Tr}(A(t)) \text{det}(p_{1}(t),...,p_{n}(t)) = \text{Tr}(A(t))W(t) $$
$$ \text{So, }~ W'(t)= \text{Tr}(A(t))W(t)  $$
Integrating above differential equation, we will get
$$ W(t)=c \text{e}^{\int_{0}^{t} \text{Tr}A(s) \text{ds}}. $$
Using initial condition $P(0)=P_{0}$, we get $c=\text{det}(P_{0}).$
$$ \text{Therefore,} ~ \text{det}(P(t))=\text{det}(P_{0})\text{e}^{\int_{0}^{t} \text{Tr}A(s) \text{ds}} $$

Comment: Thank you for your answer